# Is there an api to get the models and their attribute definitions from an ember-data store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say you have a model like so:

```
Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  description: DS.attr("string"),
});
```

Is there an api to get the models and their attribute definitions from an ember-data store?

Something that would return something like

```
{
  Recipe: {
    title: "string"
    description: "string"
  }
}
```

Reason I'm asking is I'm interested in building a generic FormView that would add appropriate inputs based on attributes and types.

Comment: Seems like I have part of the answer: calling `Recipe.metaForProperty("title")` gives me the type information I was looking for. Now I just need to get a list of properties, which should be a basic Ember thing I would assume.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself, here it is in case it helps someone else:

```
EmberCookbook.Recipe.eachComputedProperty(function(p, m) { 
  if (m.isAttribute) { console.log(m); } 
});
```

This loops over all the computed properties, and for those that are attributes outputs the metadata which contains the type and other information.

Comment: Could you add an example on how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

In ember-data 2.3.0 (and probably before), you can get the `attributes` property on the Model class. It is a map by attribute name of attribute meta data. See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_attributes.